# Engine Testing: Rendering a Cube on the Screen (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rendering

First off, I'd like to state that all I'm doing here is just trying to test out the capability of my OpenGL knowledge, nothing more.

The following code represents an infinite loop which does what it can to render a cube on the screen, and then keeps it in a static projection. For whatever reason, it refuses to show. On top of that, rather than having a background color of white, I get a background color of black instead.

**Code**

*MainLoop*

```
const int FIELD_OF_VIEW_Y = 60;

        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluPerspective( FIELD_OF_VIEW_Y, 640.0 / 480.0, 1.0, 1028 );

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );

        glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, -2.0f );

        Vector3f cam( 0, 0, 0 );

        QPoint3F position( 3, 3, 3 );

        const double CUBE_SIZE = 1;

        while( true )
        {
            while( SDL_PollEvent( mEvent ) )
            {
                TestCubeRender( CUBE_SIZE, cam, position );
                mControls->DoKeyHandling( mEvent );
                mCamera->ReceiveInput( mEvent->key );
                mCamera->UpdateCamera();
            }
        }
```

*TestCubeRender*

```
void TestCubeRender( const double size, const Vector3f& cameraPos, const QPoint3F& position)
    {   
        glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );

        int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
        int y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
        int z1 = 0, z2 = 0;

        x1 = ( position.x() - size );
        x2 = position.x() + size;

        y1 = ( position.y() - size );
        y2 = position.y() + size;

        z1 = ( position.z() - size );
        z2 = position.z() + size;

        qreal camZ = cameraPos.Z;
        qreal camY = cameraPos.Y;
        qreal camX = cameraPos.X;

        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );

        //glOrtho( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glPushMatrix();

        //glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, -10.0 );

        /*
         * if axis > mCamera.axis; then normal3f -1.0 on the axis.
         *      axis point is axis1
         * else if axis < mCamera.axis; then nomral3f 1.0 on the axis.
         *      axis point is axis2
         */

        /* Pattern: one axis is written twice, with the other variant of the same axis written twice as well, then the
         * order at which those axes are written is flipped, yet still following the same pattern.
         * Pattern2: one type of axis is still written twice, and the other group of the same axis written twice as well,
         * the only difference being that the first group is written once, with the next group written twice, and then that
         * first group written once again. The third axis type is written using one type, depending on the camera comparisons.
         */

        glBegin( GL_QUADS );

        glColor4f( 1.0, 0, 1, 1 );

        if ( z1 <= camZ )
        {
            glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0, -1.0 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y1, z1 ); //1
            glVertex3i( x1, y2, z1 ); //1
            glVertex3i( x2, y2, z1 ); //1
            glVertex3i( x2, y1, z1 ); //1
        }

        if ( z2 >= camZ )
        {
            glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y1, z2 ); //2
            glVertex3i( x2, y2, z2 ); //2
            glVertex3i( x1, y2, z2 ); //2
            glVertex3i( x1, y1, z2 ); //2
        }

        glColor4f( 0, 1, 0, 1 );

        if ( y1 >= camY )
        {
            glNormal3f( 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y1, z1 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y1, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y1, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y1, z1 );
        }

        if ( y2 <= camY )
        {
            glNormal3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y2, z1 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y2, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y2, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y2, z1 );
        }

        glColor4f( 1, 0, 0, 1 );

        if ( x1 >= camX )
        {
            glNormal3f( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y1, z1 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y1, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y2, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x1, y2, z1 );
        }

        if ( x2 <= camX )
        {
            glNormal3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y2, z1 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y2, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y1, z2 );
            glVertex3i( x2, y1, z1 );
        }

        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

I've debugged and debugged this many, many times. I know the values should at least be displaying *something*. If I could even just see my background color change, I'd at least know something is being done properly. **What should I do?**

Comment: Are you sure you are swapping the buffers on your window?

Comment: Where's your `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things missing: Setting the viewport (`glViewport`) to window interior size. Swapping the buffers after rendering ( `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers`).

Comment: glViewport by default covers all window area for which OpenGL context has been created.

Comment: Only until the first resizing. When a OpenGL context is attached to a drawable for the first time (and only then) the initial viewport dimensions are set. Subsequent changes in window size must be reflected by an appropriate call to glViewport.

Comment: Of course. But that wouldn't explain why nothing gets shown on display.